# Amazon s3 Bucket Serverless Image Handler Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, thumbor

I deployed Serverless Image Handler to S3 bucket with using this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/welcome.html). And it was successfull.

Also i tried Demo UI and it's working. But i can not get images in S3 bucket with Thumbor image requests. Like this;

```
https://<distName>.cloudfront.net/fit-in/500x500/image.png
```

For my current images when i add "fit-in/500x500" to url it gives "AccessDenied" error.

For urls produced by Serverless Image Handler Demo UI it says;

```
{ 
   "status":400,
   "code":"RequestTypeError",
   "message":"The type of request you are making could not be processed. Please ensure that your original image is of a supported file type (jpg, png, tiff, webp) and that your image request is provided in the correct syntax. Refer to the documentation for additional guidance on forming image requests."
}
```

How can i make current buckets working with Serverless Image Handler by url?

Comment: what is you bucket policy ? Do you have this type or principal in your bucket policy ?? 
"Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity <your cloudfront access id>"
            }

Comment: Principal, exactly it's the same in your example "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user.....

Comment: make sure you have ORIGIN BEHAVIOR for the png files in your cloudfront distribution

Comment: Did you solve it? I am getting the same error as well. Followed the same guide.